# Visual Studio Code with Pylance cannot resolve imports while using hatch

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, hatch

When I created my project using `hatch new name` imports were resolved correctly. Now that I opened it again I get yellow squigly line under each import with error in tooltip:

```py
from django.conf import settings # -> Import "django.conf" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)
```

I understand this error happens when vscode finds wrong python executable (usually global one instead of venv one). So when not using hatch I could resolve it by creating `.vscode/settings.json` file with content like:

```json
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path/to/venv"
}
```

However in this project I am using `hatch` build tool, which manages environments itself (at least I cannot find them in project directory). **How do I point vscode to correct python interpreter in this case?**

Edit:

I tried changing venv location by adding `dirs.env` to my `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[dirs.env]
virtual = ".hatch"
```

Then I deleted existing default environment using `hatch env prune` and creating it again using `hatch env create`. However `hatch env find default` still shows old location and `.hatch` was not created:

```
$ hatch env find default
C:\Users\Matija\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\cq\bnqHl4TX\cq
```

Adding new environment to `pyproject.toml` and creating it using `hatch env create vsc` also creates it in `AppData` instead of in `.hatch`:

In `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.hatch.envs.vsc]
```

Commands:

```
$ hatch env create vsc
$ hatch env find vsc
C:\Users\Matija\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\cq\bnqHl4TX\vsc
```

Comment: Have you solved it? The same happens to me...

Comment: @JunKim not really - I stopped using hatch for unrelated reasons. One possible workaround is to have local manually created venv with installed dependencies, so you have autocomplete at least, and use hatch venv for everything else. I didn't find a reliable solution.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! I will put it as Stackoverflow answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, using the below solved it:

```yaml
[tool.hatch.envs.default]
path = ".hatch"
```

instead of

```yaml
[dirs.env]
virtual = ".hatch"
```

I think `[tool.hatch.envs.default]` has a higher priority than `[dirs.env]`.

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing. `dirs.env` sets the directory and then each env comes below that. `tool.hatch.envs.default` sets the directory explicitly for the default env only. Close enough in many cases, but if you want different environments (e.g different python versions or dependencies) then this isn't quite it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing `pyproject.toml`, you can set the value on the command line.

```bash
hatch config set dirs.env.virtual .hatch
```

Note that `hatch env find` is a useful command to make sure its looking where you want it to look.

Answer (score -1):

##### You need to choose the *correct* interpreter for VSCODE.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`

  [image]

The setting of `python.defaultInterpreterPath` is the default interpreter when you open a new workspace without choosing an interpreter. If you choose another one by **Select Interpreter** panel, then it will not work in this workspace

##### Explanation of `python.defaultInterpreterPath` setting:

> Path to default Python to use when extension loads up for the first time, no longer used once an interpreter is selected for the workspace. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Setting-descriptions#pythondefaultinterpreterpath) to understand when this is used

Comment: I know how to set correct intepreter, this question is about more specific problem - that is how to set correct interpreter when using hatch's venv.